# AngularJS Json array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

I am trying to build an array of object using AngularJS.

Fisrt I start with only 1 object. When the user click on a button it add a object to my array.

This is the button part that is working;

**HTML**:

```
<button ng-click="ajoutForme()" type="button" class="btn btn-default">+</button>
```

**Angular**:

```
$scope.ajoutForme = function(){
    $scope.nbrForme++;

}
```

This is working as expected and I can see nbrForme incrementing on the page.

But this button is actually adding a row to be filled in my table. So everytime the button is clicked I want to insert a new row to my table.

I do the following;

**Angular**:

```
$scope.row = [];

$scope.$watch('nbrForme', function() {
 for(i=0;  i<nbrForme; i++){
  $scope.row.push({
    id: i
  });  
 }
});
```

Since I am watching the `nbrForme`. Everytime the button is pressed a new object is created inside the array `row`.

I am displaying the `row` array on my page to see the changes and I do it like this:

**HTML**:

row = {{row}}

So before I press the button I have only one object with an id of 0;
Everytime I press the button I can see the new object getting added to the array but the id is always 0.

So im getting an output that look like:

```
row = [{"id":0},{"id":0},{"id":0},{"id":0},{"id":0}]
```

So I am wondering why the `var i` is not being incremented.

Comment: Why don't you just push it inside the `ajoutForme` function?

Comment: Even if I do that 'i' is not being incremented

Comment: But it is working if I use nbrForme and drop the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
$scope.nbrForme = 0;
$scope.row = [];
$scope.ajoutForme = function(){
    $scope.row.push({
        id: $scope.nbrForme++
    });
}
```

Comment: @Abhishek, your demo made me realize that i was missing `$scope` thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can try it

```
$scope.ajoutForme = function(){
    $scope.nbrForme++;
    $scope.row.push({
            id: $scope.nbrForme
    }); 
}
```

when you used

```
for(i=0;  i<nbrForme; i++){
  $scope.row.push({
    id: i
  });  
 }
```

every time starting push in `row` from `0` to `nbrForme`. so you pushed duplicate object that unexpected and may will show error when try to show in DOM using `ng-repeat` without `track by`.